# PowerBI Apply slicer using Button

Tags: button, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I am  trying to apply the slicer or filter using Button in Power BI. I have one date column in data and want a button which will slice values for only one date on all visuals in one page.
I have created two bookmarks, one with all values and other with only one date. Bookmarks are working fine ,but when I am I using same bookmarks in Button actions are not doing anything.
Is it possible to use slicer bookmarks with Buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why bookmark was not working under button. In Power BI Button works with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click. After adding bookmark to action, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click on button will do the action.
if  anyone has any other solution , please post here.

Comment: That is the only solution because it's working as intended.